# новичковое задание на кодварс Java (получение разделенной строки и создание массива)

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Друзья, не могу разобраться, протолкните пожалуйста:

Метод вызывается с параметром

```
Solution.whoLikesIt("Alex", "Jacob", "Mark", "Max");
```

или

```
Solution.whoLikesIt();
```

Что передается - строка или массив? Эти имена я должен поймать как элементы массива. В методе у меня так:

```
public static String whoLikesIt(String[] names) {...}
```

Нельзя перебирать элементы names, не работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Хорошо что спросил, а не продолжил искать решение сам. Работающее решение выглядит так, если кому понадобится: class Solution {
    public static String whoLikesIt(String... names) {
    if (names.length == 0) {return "nothing";}
    return names[0] + ", length:" + names.length;
    }
System.out.println(Solution.whoLikesIt("Alex", "Jacob", "Mark", "Max"));
}

Answer (score 0):

А если сделать  так

```
public static String whoLikesIt(String... names)  {...}
```

Varargs — это аргументы переменной длины: фича, которая появилась еще в JDK5. Varargs позволяют нам создавать методы с произвольным количеством аргументов

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html